# Localization sqlite files in an app titanium

Tags: sqlite, localization, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I'm developing an app with titanium in two languages​​.
I am look for advice on how to translate the fields in my sqlite database.
I want to do it better. It makes sense to create two fields in the table for language(desc_en / desc_es)?
Then call the field based on the language (Ti.Platform.Local)?

Tips, tutorials? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dynamically changing column based on user's language, you could include a [language] column in each relevant table:

```
                 PRODUCTS
                 productid
                 languageid
                 productname

                 composite primary key (productid, languageid) 


                 1 | english | widget                    
                 1 | russian | виджет
```

That would make it much easier to support new languages -- no need to change table schemas.

Comment: please forgive me, but are a little confused.
I have to create a 'language' table with which to make the joins?
Now I have a table
`PRODUCTS
p_id | p_name | p_desc_en | p_desc_es`
So I change in
`PRODUCTS
p_id | p_name

LAUNGUAGE
l_id | l_name | p_id | p_desc`

I am newbie to SLQ.

Comment: A LANGUAGES table is not absolutely necessary by any means. If you made languageid intelligible, e.g. 'english', or a standard abbreviation whose meaning is apparent, then you would not absolutely require a LANGUAGES table to "explain" the value. You would simply append `and languageid = 'xx' ` to your where-clause whenever you needed to retrieve language-specific data.

Comment: Ok,
I think I understand, so I will have a product for each row in a language.
But as I understand it this way untranslated fields will be duplicated?
I will have an advantage in the where clause which will put the variable of language.

Comment: I do not understand your question: `untranslated fields will be duplicated?`  The approach I suggested does not duplicate `fields|columns` in any way. The example PRODUCTS table would contain more rows but far fewer columns than the alternative, where there are as many product-name columns as there are languages (english, russian, spanish, italian, japanese, etc): `englishProductName, russianProductName, spanishProductName, italianProductName, japaneseProductName`, etc.

Comment: In my case I have a table PRODUCTS: cost_p, name_p, fav_p desc_p. Only the desc_p column is translated and not the others. So I thought to change the desc column in two column: desc_lang. Then use a variable in the query: desc_VAR. Also because my app will always and only in two languages​​.
Thank you so much for the brainstorming

Comment: `because my app will always and only in two languages​​`.  If you take the approach you have in mind, that's pretty much guaranteed. ;-)